# Monotone and Bounded Sequences

Tags: analysis

Determine whether the given sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent by deciding on monotonicity and boundness. Explain your answer.

$$\{a_n\}=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$$

Comment: Since you are new to this site, please consider reading this: [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) I wrote this comment because the question sounds homework-like.

Comment: Are you having trouble determining whether the sequence is monotonic?  Determining whether the sequence is bounded?  Showing that monotonic bounded sequences are convergent?  What sort of trouble is it?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to express
$$a_n = A + \dfrac{B}{2n+1}$$
In this way you can prove boundedness and monotonicity.

Comment: And even the limit!